# tableView not equal to searchResultsTableView after returning to tab

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a `UITabBarController` with 4 tabs containing identical `UINavigationController`s + `UITableViewController`s. Each one has a `UISearchBar` and `UISearchDisplayController` and implement all delegate methods. First I click on any tab, tap the search bar, enter text and press search. I placed a log inside the `numberOfSectionsInTableView` to see how the view controller is recognising the frontmost table view (for now I'm just returning zero results).

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        NSLog(@"Search Controller is the current table view");
        return 0;
    } else
        NSLog(@"Search Controller is not the current table view");

    return self.itemSections.count;
}
```

This time the first statement is printed in the console.

I then (without dismissing the search controller) change the tab and then straight away go back to the first tab (with the search controller). The search controller is still the frontmost view however the second log statement is printed rather than the other.

If I change:

```
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
```

to:

```
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView || self.searchDisplayController.isActive)
```

then the second criteria in the new if-statement allows the controller to behave the way it should. My question is why is `tableView` in the `numberOfSectionsInTableView` method not equal to `self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView` when `self.searchDisplayController` is active?

Comment: What code do you have to reload the two table views and where do you have it?

Comment: The data source and table is reloaded in `viewDidAppear`, is that important?

Comment: @sooper try to not reload the table in viewDidAppear?

Comment: Something causes the wrong table view to reload when you switch tabs, you need to find out what it is...